# cin.getline ignoring first word?

Tags: c++, getline

I'm having a problem with `cin.getline();`. cin.getline is ignoring the first word

```
cout << endl << "Insert the reason: " << endl <<"> ";
cin >> Reason;
cin.getline(Reason,200);
```

I think thats how you do it anyway. I'm not sure if the problem is here, or when I input it into a file:

```
myfile.open("BudgetLog.txt", ios::app);
myfile << endl << "Time: " << Date << " " << Time << "\t\tAmount taken: " << Amount << "\t\tReason: " << Reason << " \t\tAmount left: " << CurrentAmount <<endl;
myfile.close();
```

Comment: You have not told us what is actually wrong. What problem are you having?

Comment: @BjörnPollex, it's in the title :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you first read the reason with `operator>>` (the first word), then you read the rest (overwriting the result of `>>`) with `getline()`.

Answer (score 0):

use 1 instruction only

```
cin >> Reason;
```

or

```
cin.getline(Reason,200);
```